# bootstrap doesn't show <ul> and <ol> lists

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple code where I want to display ordered and unordered lists.
I use Bootstrap but I don't see any list style, no numbers no bullets.

```
<ul>
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>
</ul>
<br />
<ol>
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>
</ol>
```

what I get :

[image]

Comment: it does show it..check your styles and see if you have not mistakenly made list-style:none;

Comment: Check `margin`. Can you reproduce the issue in http://www.bootply.com/new or https://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lists are probably getting displayed but its hidden behind the screen.

```
<div style="margin-left:20px;">
    <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <ol>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
    </ol>
 </div>
```